# Log batch in listbox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, minecraft

I am currently working on a program, that can handle Minecraft servers. I am running my batch witch logs the server, and i now want the batch (called batch in my code) to log in my listbox called lg_log.

If it is possible, how can I do that?

I am programming in visual studio - Windows forms in c#.

Edit: This is my code:

```
Process batch = new Process();

string PathtoRunFile = @"\Servers\Base\start_server.bat";
string current_directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string server_base = @"\Servers\Base";
string working_directory = current_directory + server_base;

batch.StartInfo.FileName = current_directory + PathtoRunFile;
batch.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
batch.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = working_directory;

batch.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
batch.Start();
```

Comment: Are you using `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`?

Comment: All those edits and no one beat the witch with her broomstick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Process.StartInfo` contains properties like `RedirectStandardOutput`. By setting this flag to `true`, you will be able to add an event handler to `batch.StartInfo.OutputDataReceived` and listen for any events. Somewhat like so:

**Edit:** You might also want to enable redirecting the ErrorOutput in order to receive error messages.

**Edit:** As requested, here is a fully working example. Make sure that `test.bat` exists.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var form = new Form {ClientSize = new Size(400, 300)};
        var button = new Button {Location = new Point(0, 0), Text = "Start", Size = new Size(400, 22)};
        var listBox = new ListBox {Location = new Point(0, 22), Size = new Size(400, 278)};
        form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {button, listBox});

        button.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo("test.bat") {UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true};
            var proc = new Process {StartInfo = info, EnableRaisingEvents = true};
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (obj, args) => {
                if (args.Data != null) {
                    listBox.Items.Add(args.Data);
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        };

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! As Nekresh said, you should post your existing code into your first post. Also, if it answered your question, please consider accepting it as such :) **Edit:** Oh, and welcome to SO!

Comment: sorry :( can't get it to work - Could you write an example for me? :D

Comment: I forgot to mention that the UseShellExecute property of the ProcessStartInfo object must be false. Does that fix your issue? The code above has been updated.

Comment: Console applications can write to both STDOUT and STDERR so you should capture both. You can use the same data received handler for both which will preserve the order of the output between the two streams.